# Overwriting a python.txt file to save only the last 3 entries per Name

Tags: python

I have a quiz program that saves user scores to a file. I have a function that looks at all the scores under a persons name in the file and outputs their average score, but what I need is it to only take into account the last 3 scores per name. This is my code so far

```
with open("highscoresclass1.txt") as f:
d = {}

for line in f:
    column = line.split(":")
    names = column[0]
    scores = int(column[1].strip())

    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
        count = count + 1

averages=[]
for name, v in d.items():
    average = (sum(v)/len(v))
    averages.append((name, average))

for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
    print(name, average)
```

Comment: Can you show the sample text file?

Comment: @Optimus i dont know how to post a picture but the scores for say 'Joe' are 0 first then 3 10's so i dont want it to take into account the 0 if you understand?

Comment: Chris:0
Kit:4
Joe:0
Joe:10
Joe:10
Joe:10

Comment: ``average = (sum(v[-3:])/len(v[-3:]))``?

Comment: @greschd Thank you very much this seems to have worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("highscoresclass1.txt") as f:
d = {}

for line in f:
    column = line.split(":")
    names = column[0]
    scores = int(column[1].strip())

    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
        count = count + 1

averages=[]
for name, v in d.items():
    average = (sum(v[-3:])/len(v[-3:]))
    averages.append((name, average))

for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
    print(name, average)
```

Thank you